# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable - Data generator

Tags: python, error-handling, nonetype

I created a list out of two other lists which looks like this:

```
samples = list(map(lambda x, y: [x,y], image_path, labels8))
[['s01_l01/1_1.png', '7C2 4698'],
 ['s01_l01/2_1.png', '7C2 4698'],
 ['s01_l01/2_2.png', '7C2 4698'],
 ['s01_l01/2_3.png', '7C2 4698'],
 ['s01_l01/2_4.png', '7C2 4698']]
```

The first entry is the image_path, the second a label.

I also created this function:

```
def shuffle_data(data):
  data=random.shuffle(data)
  return data
```

To get a data_generator, I modified the code I found in a video on YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkzB6PJIcCA&t=530s):

```
def data_generator(samples, batch_size=32, shuffle_data = True, resize=224):
  num_samples = len(samples)
  while True:
    samples = random.shuffle(samples)

    for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
      batch_samples = samples[offset: offset + batch_size]

      X_train = []
      y_train = []

      for batch_sample in batch_samples:
        img_name = batch_sample[0]
        label = batch_sample[1]
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(root_dir, img_name))

        #img, label = preprocessing(img, label, new_height=224, new_width=224, num_classes=37)
        img = preprocessing(img, new_height=224, new_width=224)
        label = my_onehot_encoded(label)

        X_train.append(img)
        y_train.append(label)

      X_train = np.array(X_train)
      y_train = np.array(y_train)

      yield X_train, y_train
```

When I now try to execute this code:

```
train_datagen = data_generator(samples, batch_size=32)

x, y = next(train_datagen)
print('x_shape: ', x.shape)
print('labels shape: ', y.shape)
print('labels: ', y)
```

I got the following error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-6adc7f4509cd> in <module>()
      1 train_datagen = data_generator(samples, batch_size=32)
      2 
----> 3 x, y = next(train_datagen)
      4 print('x_shape: ', x.shape)
      5 print('labels shape: ', y.shape)

<ipython-input-88-0f34e3e5c990> in data_generator(samples, batch_size, shuffle_data, resize)
      5 
      6     for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
----> 7       batch_samples = samples[offset: offset + batch_size]
      8 
      9       X_train = []

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I don't get where the error is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`random.shuffle` is in-place and returns `None`.

So, write

```
random.shuffle(samples)
```

instead of

```
samples = random.shuffle(samples)
```

Comment: Ok, and what do I have to do in this case?

Comment: Sorry, just edited answer to answer your upcoming question ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! :) One related question: In the original code, the author coded: `def shuffle_data(data): data=shuffle(data) return data`. But since I got the error code that shuffle is not defined, I used `random.shuffle`. Now I am wondering if there is any difference regarding the two methods?

Comment: That might indeed be the root cause. Maybe the author had another `shuffle` function. I am however not aware of a *standard* one. Also the one in `numpy.random` is in-place.

Comment: But there should not be any difference between the two methods and my code should work fine as well, isn't it? :)

Answer (score 1):

`random.shuffle` is an in-place operation, so you shouldn't be assigning its result (which is `None`) to the shufflee. Instead, leave it as is:

```
while True:
    random.shuffle(samples) # <--here

    for offset in range(0, num_samples, batch_size):
        batch_samples = samples[offset: offset + batch_size]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)